# Why Sql Is Returning Wrong Result?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

`Id` Column is `unique` and `primary(auto increment)`.

Check Screenshot Below.

I don't get it why it is returning result on a wrong id.

[image]

Comment: `id` is equal to 3 NOT what you are using in the query. _There are none so blind as will not see_

Comment: it didn't return a wrong result, it returned zero rows, that's what you asked for

Comment: Select * from images where id=3 ?

Comment: query should return null but id='3d-569-300x188' is matching with record 3 from database.. thats what i my asking it should return zero records.. but is returning id 3 from nowhere

Comment: @Fred-ii- no it is returning one row.. check screenshot again

Comment: *Showing rows 0 - 0*

Comment: mysql took the closest match then where it found a leading "3". what's the question about here?

Comment: @Fred-ii- 1(total) check that again

Comment: @Gorki lol true, see my other comment just above. ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- lol i want exact match only? any help

Comment: @gmiley it's not what the question about. Gorki is wondering "why" it's returning that.

Comment: How many records are in your table? And what is the structure of your table?

Comment: not more than 1000

Comment: @Gorki what is the id column's type here? Plus you had the php tag in there earlier with no code for it. do you have php for it?

Comment: id is int(255) primary unique

Comment: `int(255)` - that's way too high

Comment: its 25 mistyped

Comment: ok well what I think is going on here, is that MySQL thinks those characters are valid such as `-` for minus (for math) and `x` for multiplication, therefore it could be valid syntax. However, the creation of that record alone should have thrown you an error for it.

Comment: Got Answer SELECT * FROM images WHERE CAST(id AS CHAR) = '3d-659-300x188'; it is returning null on wrong id. not matching the closest match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what your problem is here. Your query `select * from images where id = '3d-blahblah';` is actually **implicitly** converting your `varchar` value into an number (in this case `3`) since your `id` field is of a numeric type.

Read through the following page for more information on type conversions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html

Comment: Well, you can't really. Your `id` field is a `numeric` type. You should be searching for `numeric` values not `varchar`.

Comment: SELECT * FROM images WHERE CAST(id AS CHAR) = '3d-659-300x188'; it is working

Comment: Sure that will work, but there will never be that string in the `id` column as a `numeric` type can never contain a `varchar`. There is no point in trying to compare the two. Not to mention any indexes will never be used if you do that.

Comment: I would instead ensure that the value you are trying to search for is of a `numeric` type. If it isn't why bother to run the query in the first place?

Comment: i m using this query only in function to check unnecessary images in folder. all images are saved w.r.t to id. so if any file does not match with id so i can unlink it easily